# Using Meteor subscriptions in React

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I am using `React.js` with `Meteor.js`, and am trying to use Meteor's [subscribe](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe) within React, based on [a blog post](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/subscriptions-and-data-management/with-react) that I'm reading. My thinking here, and please correct me if I'm wrong (I am new to react) is that every time the database changes, specifically the `wait` collection, the front end will change to reflect this (I will eventually be finding a median value).

However, I'm running into an issue with `Meteor.subscribe('wait')`, which is supposed to be returning a selection of the mongo collection, but is not. This, I believe, is leading to the error message that I am currently getting, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. When I log the returned data (as shown), I am just getting `undefined`. I know the query works because when I run it inside of Meteor.isServer it returns one of the documents from the collection.

So how can I use getMeteorData (shown below) to return data from the `wait` collection, and have it update the `waitTime` DOM object whenever there are changes (new documents added, etc.) to the database?

```
Venue = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var self = this;
    var venueName = this.props.params.venueName;
    return (
      <div className='venue'>
        <h1>This is the Venue {venueName}</h1>
        <WaitTime />
        <div className='wait-time-chooser'>
          <div className="red" onClick={self.waitTime.bind(this,venueName,'red')}>RED</div>
          <div className="yellow" onClick={self.waitTime.bind(this,venueName,'yellow')}>YELLOW</div>
          <div className="green" onClick={self.waitTime.bind(this,venueName,'green')}>GREEN</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  waitTime(currentVenue,time) {
    sendWaitTime(currentVenue,time);
  }
});
function sendWaitTime(venue,time) {
  var userId = Meteor.user()._id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wait?venue=" + venue + "&wait=" + time + "&user=" + userId,
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response){
      console.log("Error:" + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
  });  
}

WaitTime = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>WAIT TIME: {!$.isEmptyObject(this.data)? this.data.wait : <p>Loading...</p>}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  },  
  componentDidMount() {  
    // wait for task...
  },
  getMeteorData() {
    var data = {};
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('wait');
    if(handle.ready()) {
      data.wait = Wait.findOne({});
      console.log(data);
    }
    return data;
  }  
});
```

Comment: Can you post your publication code? Why are you `post`ing to the server instead of using a Meteor method?

Comment: @MasterAM what would you suggest as an alternative to using `post`? I am sending a request from the server to an API, using the parameters shown here. I'll put up the publication code

Comment: Call the API from a meteor method on the server. You can even use the synchronous syntax in the method if this is a normal http request, which simplifies the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it (thanks to the comments and reading [this Meteor Doc](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe)). Had to do the following on the server:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('wait', function waitPublication() {
    return Wait.find();
  });
}
```

I guess I had already removed [autopublish](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/autopublish), `meteor remove autopublish`, which comes with Meteor by default.